# Prove that $ a^2 = \lvert a \rvert^2$, Is my proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

So I tried to prove the following basic theorem:

$$ \forall a \in  \mathbb{R}:  a^2 = \lvert a \rvert^2$$

My attempt:

Consider equation for $a\ge0$ and $a\le0$ in relation to the formal definition of absolute values $\lvert x \rvert$

$$|x| = \begin{cases}x & x \ge 0\\-x & x<0\end{cases}$$

$(i)$ for $a\ge0$ :

$$\begin{align} a ^2 & = \lvert a \rvert \times \lvert a \rvert \\ 
&= a \times a \\  
&= a^2
 \end{align}$$

$(ii)$ for $a\le0$ :

$$\begin{align} a ^2 & = \lvert a \rvert \times \lvert a \rvert \\ 
&= (-a) \times (-a) \\ 
&= a^2
 \end{align}$$

Does my proof hold correctly? Feedback is welcome!

Comment: Your proof is fine, but one aspect of the presentation I would point out is that you started by asserting the desired equality in each case, and then got down to a true statement. Do the opposite, so something like
\begin{align}
a^2 & = a \times a \\
& = |a| \times |a| \\
& = |a|^2
\end{align}

Comment: All you seem to have proved (if I am seeing your MathJax correctly) is that $a^2=a^2$ in both cases. Do you mean $|a|^2=|a|\times|a|$ etc.?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm reading too fast.

Comment: These are not sound arguments. What each shows is that if $a^2=|a|^2$ then $a^2=a^2$. This implication is automatic and does not demonstrate that $a^2=|a|^2$. Now if you were to replace $a^2$ in the first line of each calculation by $|a|^2$...